# Select Box select issue in IOS Ipad mini

Tags: ios, html, css, ipad

i am trying to show select box  with scroll in IOS ipad mini.

**Problem** : Option is not coming in select box. it is coming out of select box   in POP over.

**css**

```
.indicators_geography {
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 105px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 169px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="indicators_geography" name="" multiple="multiple" id="" size="10">
<option is_adjustment="0" title="" value="2593">011</option>
<option is_adjustment="0" title="" value="2593">012</option>
<option is_adjustment="0" title="" value="2593">013</option>
<option is_adjustment="0" title="" value="2593">013</option>
<option is_adjustment="0" title="" value="2593">014</option>
</select>
```

OPTION VALUES ARE DUMMY. PLEASE IGNORE.

**sCREEN SHOT.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want it to be scrollable, so have you tried applying css of simple overflow: scroll instead of overflow-x?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/79tamt03/ is this what you want? If not, could you provide a fiddle of your problem